# Guice: differences between Singleton.class and @Singleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

In Guice, what's the difference between:

```
// Inside your AbstractModule subclass:
@Override
public void configure() {
    bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

And:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
}

@Provides @Singleton
public ServiceImpl providesService() {
    return new ServiceImpl();
}
```

Are they both the same? When would you use one versus the other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

They are **nearly** identical. The `@Singleton` syntax is useful for annotating `@Provides` methods, or annotating the class itself (though I prefer to keep my scoping annotations inside modules).

The difference lies in *which key is marked Singleton*, which has less to do with `@Singleton` versus `Singleton.class` (or `Scopes.SINGLETON`, `asEagerSingleton`, `@Singleton` class annotations, or `toInstance` implicit singletons) and more to do with what the default syntax makes easy. For example:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

    bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class);
    bind(BImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }

  @Provides @Singleton C provideC() { return new CImpl(); }

  @Provides @Singleton D provideD(DImpl dImpl) { return dImpl; }

  @Provides E provideE(EImpl eImpl) { return eImpl; }
  @Provides @Singleton EImpl provideEImpl() { return new EImpl(); }
}
```

Above we've bound interface `A` to class `AImpl`, and interface `B` to class `BImpl`, but the behavior is different:

- Injecting `A` will retrieve the same `AImpl` instance every time.
- Injecting `AImpl` will retrieve a different `AImpl` every time, all of which are different than `A`'s instance.
- Injecting `B` will retrieve the same `BImpl` instance every time.
- Injecting `BImpl` will also retrieve that same `BImpl` instance that `B` injects.

As you can see, each key is different, and Guice will allow multiple implementation instances if only the interface is bound with Singleton. If you only ever inject `A` and `B` interfaces, the behavior looks identical, but if you inject both interfaces and implementations from the same Injector, you may see differing behavior.

Similar logic goes for `@Provides` methods:

- Injecting `C` will always return the same `CImpl` instance.
- Injecting `CImpl` will create a new `CImpl` every time, unless `CImpl` has no injectable public zero-arg constructor—then the injection will fail.
- Injecting `D` will always return the same `DImpl` instance.
- Injecting `DImpl` will return a new instance every time, and each will be different than the one returned by `D`.
- Injecting `E` will return the same `EImpl` instance every time.
- Injecting `EImpl` will also retrieve that same instance `E` injects.

This provides some flexibility. Imagine a hypothetical `Cache` that keeps a certain number of most-recently-retrieved objects, where you want to have `@User Cache` and `@Product Cache` both injectable. If you `bind(Cache.class).in(Singleton.class)`, you will have one Cache shared between the objects (and any bare `Cache` injections), whereas if you `bind(Cache.class).annotatedWith(User.class).to(Cache.class).in(Singleton.class)` then the annotated key is kept in singleton scope and each object type will have its own cache.

Comment: I have a situation where they seem to behave differently. Using the bind statement did not restrict to just 1 instance. However, using @Singleton it worked.

Comment: @EFreak: Updated answer. It's not exactly about the difference in syntax, but with a fresh look at the question, there's some subtlety there.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly the problem I was facing yesterday. Although, I have an edit suggestion. Will update the answer.

Comment: I sort of think I understand this.  In my case I have a concrete class LoggingConfiguration bound like so:
   

 bind(LoggingConfiguration.class).in(Singleton.class);
 injector = Guice.createInjector(bindingModule);
 return injector.getInstance(ProductsLogging.class).getLogger(clazz);

   
Will there only be one throughout the vm?

Comment: @ggb667 Assuming ProductsLogging injects LoggingConfiguration, then I would guess (from what little you've told me) that every injection of LoggingConfiguration would be the same instance including in ProductsLogging. I couldn't tell you about the logger returned by `getLogger`, because that depends on the implementation of ProductsLogging. If you want a deeper analysis with more details, I think you might be better served by asking a separate question, and please make sure to include your code about how you're injecting LoggingConfiguration and which classes you want only one instance of.