# Creating Singleton in java using guice

Tags: java, singleton, guice

```
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import static com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector;

public final class BatchFactory {

      private static class Holder {
          private static final Injector INJECTOR = createInjector(new BatchModule());
          private static final batchProvider PROVIDER_INSTANCE = INJECTOR
                  .getInstance(BatchProvider.class);
      }

      public static BatchProvider getProviderInstance() {
          return Holder.PROVIDER_INSTANCE;
      }
  }

public class BatchModule extends AbstractModule {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
          bind(BatchProvider.class).to(
                  BatchProviderImpl.class);
      }
  }
```

`BatchProvider` is the Interface and `BatchProviderImpl` is the class implementation.

Here I am using a class BatchFactory to create the `@Singleton` instance of `BatchProviderImpl` class.

Can I use @Singleton annotation of google guice to make `BatchFactory` class `@Singleton`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guice: differences between Singleton.class and @Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781471/guice-differences-between-singleton-class-and-singleton)

Answer (score 3):

See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781471/guice-differences-between-singleton-class-and-singleton), you can do

```
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Or:

```
@Provides @Singleton
public ServiceImpl providesService() {
    return new ServiceImpl();
}
```