# Just in time binding in guice

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, guice

Does just in time binding in guice injects the same instance again and again or does it create a new one on every injection. In other words does it maintain singleton by default or does it create new instances everytime ?

Comment: does my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: By default, Guice creates a new instance every time.

In order to test it, we can create a small program. Let's define an interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    int getCounter();
}
```

And implementation:

```
class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface {
   private static int counter = 0;

    @Inject
    public SomeInterfaceImpl() {
       counter++;
   }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

The main program will be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(binder -> {
        binder.bind(SomeInterface.class).to(SomeInterfaceImpl.class);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        SomeInterface impl = injector.getInstance(SomeInterface.class);
        System.out.println(impl.getCounter());
    }
}
```

The output of that program will be:

```
0
1
2
```

In order to have your class singleton you have 4 options:

1. Define the class in a singleton class:

   ```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(binder -> {
        binder.bind(SomeInterface.class).to(SomeInterfaceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    });
   ```
2. Define the class in a singlton scope:

   ```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(binder -> {
        binder.bind(SomeInterface.class).to(SomeInterfaceImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    });
   ```
3. Define `SomeInterfaceImpl` as singleton:

   ```
   @Singleton
   class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface {
   ```
4. Call `asEagerSingleton`:

   ```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(binder -> {
        binder.bind(SomeInterface.class).to(SomeInterfaceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
    });
   ```

To understand more about the differences between the 4 options, you can refer to the [docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes), or read [Jeff's post about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14784362/2359227).